# Doit-on employer le pluriel après « genre », « sorte » et « type » ?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel

Faut-il dire : « ce genre de personne m’agace » ou « ce genre de personnes m’agace » ?

Doit-on mettre le substantif situé après « genre » au pluriel ?

Même question pour « cette sorte de » ou « ce type de ».

Answer (score 7):

Oserais-je dire que les deux sont valides.

Si tu n'as qu'une seule personne dont tu veux parler, tu mets au singulier, sinon, au pluriel.

Comment: J'aurais aussi tendance à utiliser les deux, mais pour moi le choix dépend plus du nombre de personnes que tu imagines dans la proposition qui les décrit, que du nombre de personnes auquel la comparaison s'applique.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Oui, tu as raison, c'est le sens que je voulais donner.

Comment: Alors tu as mon approbation, pour peu qu'elle vaille quelque chose :-)

Answer (score 2):

Même s'il est tout à fait intelligible d'entendre l'un ou l'autre, on peut se ranger du coté du Petit Robert si l'on considère que *personne* est un substantif.

Il est difficile de mettre au pluriel *"ce genre de cheval*", il faudrait alors dire "**ces** *genres de chevaux*", qui n'est pas très usuel ... à moins de dire qu'il y a plusieurs races distinctes dans le groupe sous nos yeux.

Pour les *genre, type,* et *sorte* dont il est questions ici, on évoque un paradigme d'une propriété particulière ... paradigme par définition unique, sinon ce n'en est plus un au sens strictement logique.

Pour un écrit recherché, je resterai donc fidèle à mon dictionnaire préféré.

Mettre au pluriel sous-entend un ajout : *ce genre (de groupe) de personnes*, ou *de type de personnes (groupées)* [je ne peux m'empêcher de laisser *groupe* au singulier].

Il y a un problème d'œil : si l'on voit plusieurs personnes (avec les yeux  ou au travers d'une image mentale) la vision l'emporte sur l'audition car l'œil capture l'ensemble et décode immédiatement, alors que l'oreille doit attendre la fin pour valider l'ensemble.

On a donc tendance à lui laisser la priorité, et d'écrire *personnes* au pluriel, surtout que le pluriel est ici inaudible (Cf. nos équidés ci-dessus).

Mais je suis incapable de vous dire s'il s'agit là d'un usage toléré ou d'une faute académique.

Answer (score 1):

"J'aime ce type / ce genre / cette sorte de vitrail" et non "de vitraux".

Les exemples à *genre* dans le Petit Robert donnent également le singulier.

Comment: Pas d'accord. Si au moment de dire cette phrase, tu désignes de la main plusieurs vitraux, l'utilisation du pluriel serait à mon sens plus adéquate...

Comment: +1 pour la référence au petit Robert